# Can we use custom label in validation rule?

Tags: validation-rule

In my validation rule, `$Profile.Name!='MyProfileName'` is there. I have to replace this by using custom label. How can i accomplish that?

Answer (score 8):

You will need to use [global variable $Label](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_label.htm)

```
$Profile.Name !=  $Label.MyProfile
```